# Deprioritizing (traffic shaping) bittorrent seeding

Tags: linux, traffic-shaping, bittorrent

I have a linux server with spare bandwidth. I thought about running an rtorrent client and seeding some popular distros images. However, I can't allow myself to curtail the normal operation of the server (I'm only willing to spare "unused" bandwidth). I thought about using rtorrent and shaping traffic using tc. After reading a bit about it, it seems that what I want to do is to use the pfifo_fast qdisc and somehow mark all of the network traffic of rtorrent as having priority 2, while the normal http server having an higher priority. However, I couldn't find an easy way to do it.

Can someone point out the right (and hopefully simple) way to do it?